# Does Kotlin support Java 11?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, jvm

I am trying to use Kotlin V1.2.70, Gradle V4.10.1 and Java 11. When compiling the project using gradle, an error saying "Unknown JVM Target Version: 11. Supported versions: 1.6, 1.8".

Does the Kotlin compiler supports Java 11 (produces code compatible with Java 11 JVM)? If so, how to configure that with gradle?

Comment: You're confusing kotlin generated bytecode version with jvm version, you can generate anything and run it on jvm 11.. which is why 90% of java devs use java 8 but run it on jvm 11...

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The bytecode generated by the Kotlin compiler, when the target version is set to either 1.6 or 1.8, is fully compatible with JVM 11.

Comment: does this mean, i have to execute gradle task  "compileKotlin" with JVM8?

Comment: No. The version of the JVM you use to run the Kotlin compiler is independent from the version of the bytecode that the compiler generates.

Comment: But when i set JVM as 11 for gradle task compileKotlin Task, i am getting error "Unknown JVM Target Version: 11. Supported versions: 1.6, 1.8"

Comment: The JVM target version in build.gradle specifies the version of the bytecode generated by the Kotlin compiler. It has nothing to do with the version of the JVM you use to execute the Gradle task. Once again: set jvmTarget to 1.8, don't worry about anything else, and everything will work.

Comment: @yole any plans to support jvmTarget beyond 1.8 or something like `kotlin-stdlib-jdk11` which includes some of the niceties added to **java 11**?

Comment: @Suresh It will be added at some point, but I can't give any specific timeframe.

Comment: Is there an open YouTrack issue to follow any developments for Java 11+ byte code support?

Answer (score 54):

The Kotlin compiler supports the JVM 9, 10, 11, and 12 bytecode versions  as target since Kotlin 1.3.30 ([changelog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/04/kotlin-1-3-30-released/)).

Prior to 1.3.30, only JVM 1.6 and 1.8 bytecode versions were supported as targets. Since you used 1.2.70, specifying JVM 11 bytecode as target led to the error you mentioned.

There are two solutions:

- Specify 1.8 as JVM target bytecode version. As @yole said in his answer, this is fully compatible with JVM 11. In fact, as mentioned in the [changelog of Kotlin 1.3.30](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/04/kotlin-1-3-30-released/), newer JVM target bytecode versions currently don't add any bytecode optimizations beyond the ones supported in 1.8, so it really doesn't make any difference for now anyway.
- Upgrade to Kotlin 1.3.30 (or newer), then you can keep 11 as the JVM bytecode target value. The advantage is that you will automatically benefit from additional bytecode optimizations in future versions of the Kotlin compiler.

Answer (score 9):

As of Kotlin 1.4, it supports Java `1.6` (default), `1.8`, `9`, `10`, `11`, `12`, `13` and `14`

> -jvm-target 
> Specify the target version of the generated JVM bytecode. Possible values are 1.6, 1.8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 and 14. The default value is 1.6.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-reference.html#-jvm-target-version

Yes, it fully supports Java 11.

Answer (score 1):

Official [Kotlin FAQ](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/faq.html#which-versions-of-jvm-does-kotlin-target) covers this question:

> #### Which versions of JVM does Kotlin target?
>
> Kotlin lets you choose the version of JVM for execution. By default, the Kotlin/JVM compiler produces Java 8 compatible bytecode. If you want to make use of optimizations available in newer versions of Java, you can explicitly specify the target Java version from 9 to 21. Note that in this case the resulting bytecode might not run on lower versions.