# Correspondence between kotlin and gradle and java version?

Tags: kotlin

Is there a corresponding relationship between kotlin and jdk versions? I see that jdk is 17. Is kotlin 1.8.21 the latest version? Does kotlin's 1.8.x refer to the jdk8 version?

May I ask if there is a relationship description for the corresponding version of kotlin?
Kotlin's description of the corresponding relationship between gradle and jdk versions?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52888341/does-kotlin-support-java-11

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/faq.html#which-versions-of-jvm-does-kotlin-target